# With JUnit 5, how to share information in `ExtensionContext.Store` between test instances?

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I am running into trouble with JUnit 5 (5.0 or 5.1) and custom extension.

We are using service loader to load all implementations which then modify how our extension is bootstrapped. These implementations can be loaded just once, so I was thinking of using `ExtensionContext.Store` and placing it there. Every subsequent test instance would then just load it from `Store` instead of via service loader.

Now, I am even aware of the hierarchical context structure and I know that there is some "root" context which you can get through `ExtensionContext.getRoot()`. But this "root" context (instance of `JupiterEngineExtensionContext`) isn't really root - there is different one for *every test instance*.

Say you have `FooTest` and `BarTest`, then printing out `getRoot()` for each of them yields:

`org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterEngineExtensionContext@1f9e9475`
`org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterEngineExtensionContext@6c3708b3`

And hence trying to retrieve previously stored information from `Store` fails.

- Is having this limitation intended? It makes the borderline between `ClassExtensionContext` and `JupiterEngineExtensionContext` pretty blurred.
- Is there another way to globally store some information via extension?

Here is a (very) simplified version of how I tried working with the store (cutting out all other information basically). I also added some `System.out.print()` calls to underline what I am seeing. Executing this extension on two **test classes** results in what I described above:

```
    public class MyExtension implements BeforeAllCallback {

    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(context.getRoot());
        if (context.getRoot().getStore(Namespace.create(MyExtension.class)).get("someIdentifier", String.class) == null) {
            context.getRoot().getStore(Namespace.create(MyExtension.class)).put("someIdentifier", "SomeFooString");
        } else {
            // this is never executed
            System.out.println("Found it, no need to store anything again!");
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here is a minimal project on GH([link](https://github.com/manovotn/YetAnotherMinimalReproducer)), run by `mvn clean install`, which displays the behaviour I see.

Comment: `getRoot()` should in fact not return different instances. How do you run your tests?

Comment: @MarcPhilipp edited question to encompass this. The code is used to check store for the value in `beforeAll` phase. If not found, it is stored and later in the extension retrieved and used. Both used tests are simply affected by this extension and execute this code.

Comment: Can you please create a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @MarcPhilipp Edited the question, there is now more complete code for the extension. Running this on two different test classes (two test instances) yields different root context instances hence nothing is saved in between calls.

Comment: As Sam wrote below, this was fixed in 1.0.3 (https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1113) but you should use 1.1.0 with Jupiter 5.1.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just copied your `MyExtension` verbatim (i.e., with zero changes) and ran both `FooTest` and `BarTest`.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;

@ExtendWith(MyExtension.class)
class FooTest {

    @Test
    void test() {
    }
}
```

and

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;

@ExtendWith(MyExtension.class)
class BarTest {

    @Test
    void test() {
    }
}
```

And the result is:

```
org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterEngineExtensionContext@2280cdac
org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterEngineExtensionContext@2280cdac
Found it, no need to store anything again!
```

Thus, `getRoot()` works as documented.

The only explanation for why you see two different roots is that you must be executing the tests in different processes.

Please keep in mind that the root `ExtensionContext` instance is bound to the current execution of your test suite.

So if you run `FooTest` and `BarTest` one after the other in an IDE, that will actually result in two "test suites" with different roots. The same is true if you configure your build tool to *fork* between test classes.

Whereas, if you execute both test classes together in a single "test suite" (e.g., by telling your IDE to run all tests in the same package or same source tree) you  will then see that there is one root like in the output I provided above.

Note, however, that there was an issue with the `junit-platform-surefire-provider` prior to version 1.0.3, whereby the provider launched the JUnit Platform for each test class. This would give the appearance of *forking* even though Surefire did not actually start a new JVM process. For details, see https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/pull/1137.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it makes perfect sense, but it still doesn't unveil my mystery, here is a minimal [project on GH](https://github.com/manovotn/YetAnotherMinimalReproducer) I created. Running it (`mvn clean install`) displays the problem. Is there some behind-the-scenes forking magic done by `junit-platform-surefire-provider`?

Comment: You're simply using the wrong version of the provider. Changing the version to `1.1.0` solves the problem!